# How to make large image on top get smaller and finally stick to the top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I want to divide my website into two parts: a header containing a large image, and a main part, containing other images, text, etc.

When I scroll the page, the large image on the header should scroll together with the main part. In a certain point, the image should become fixed, and the main part scroll behind it.

I have tried some different approaches, but I can't get the right combination of position, display, top, etc to work.

That's the closest I've got so far: https://jsfiddle.net/aor0abhf/

HTML

```
<body onscroll='scroll(event)'>
  <div class='top' id='top'><img src='http://www.vejanomapa.net.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Maria-Fuma%C3%A7a-em-Tiradentes-MG.jpg'></div>
  <div class='bottom'>
    <div class='menu'>Menu</div>
    <div class='main'><img src='http://tvulavras.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/maria-fuma%C3%A7a.jpg'></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
function scroll(e) {
    var T = document.getElementById('top');
    var imgH = T.clientHeight; // header image height
    var hH = 200; // fixed header height
    if (imgH-e.pageY > hH) { // image is scrolling
        T.style.top = '-'+e.pageY+'px';
        T.style.position = 'sticky';
    } else { // image should remain fixed
        T.style.top = '-'+(imgH-hH)+'px';
        T.style.position = 'fixed';
    }
}
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
}
body {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
img {
    display:block;
}
.top {
    background:#FCC;
  display:block;
    top:0;
}
.bottom {
    display:flex;
    min-height:1500px;
    background:#CFC;
}
.menu {
    width:100px;
    background:#CCF;
}
```

But still there's a glitch in the transition between scroll/fixed positions. And if the left menu (in light blue) could stick together, that would be great! (Maybe subject to another question?)

Comment: Instead of changing the css with javascript, you could add a class, then have your other content act differently when that class is there. For example, when active your top would be fixed, but you could also add a margin-top to your bottom equal to the height of your top & set your left menu to be fixed as well. If I have some time later and you're still working on it I'll help some more :)

Comment: @JoeLissner Change object class is faster than changing CSS properties?

Comment: @JoeLissner Can you add a working jsfiddle example, please?

Comment: Can you use jQuery? Not a big deal if not, just easier :P

Comment: well, either way, it's not perfect, but let me know if this is what you're looking for. Should at least give you an idea of what you're needing to do. https://jsfiddle.net/aor0abhf/2/

Comment: @JoeLissner Thank you, that worked perfectly! And no, I don't want to use jQuery. Please add as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your fiddle to the following:

### No Change to HTML

```
<body onscroll='scroll(event)'>
  <div class='top' id='top'><img src='http://www.vejanomapa.net.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Maria-Fuma%C3%A7a-em-Tiradentes-MG.jpg'></div>
  <div class='bottom' id='bottom'>
    <div class='menu'>Menu</div>
    <div class='main'><img src='http://tvulavras.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/maria-fuma%C3%A7a.jpg'></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
}
body {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
img {
    display:block;
}

.top {
    background:#FCC;
    display:block;
    top:0;
}

/* start new rules */

.active{
  position: fixed;
}

.active ~ .bottom {
  margin-top: 386px;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.active ~ .bottom .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/* end new rules */

.bottom {
    display:flex;
    min-height:1500px;
    background:#CFC;
}
.menu {
    min-width:100px;
    background:#CCF;
}
```

### Javascript

```
function scroll(e) {
    var T = document.getElementById('top');
    var B = document.getElementById('bottom');
    var imgH = T.clientHeight; // header image height
    var hH = 200; // fixed header height

    if (imgH-e.pageY > hH) { // image is scrolling
        T.classList.remove('active') // remove class active as applicable
        T.style.top = '-'+e.pageY+'px';
        T.style.position = 'sticky';
        B.style['margin-top'] = '0';
    } else { // image should remain fixed
        T.classList.add('active') // add class active as applicable
        T.style.top = '-'+(imgH-hH)+'px';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
min-height:1500px;
```

The div height will stay 1500px;
Try this one

```
.bottom {
    display:flex;
    background:#CFC;
}
```

This should work.

Add `margin-top:200px;` on `<div class='bottom'>` part on scroll.

Comment: I couldn't make it work. It would be great if you could provide a jsfiddle working example.